# Why CSS direct descendant selector is not applied on Angular component

Tags: html, css, angular

We have this simple `main.html`

```
<app>
   <sidebar></sidebar>
   <main-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </main-content>
</app>
```

When we load a simple component via routing (URL change), the HTML becomes:

```
<app>
   <sidebar></sidebar>
   <main-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <component></component>
   </main-content>
</app>
```

The first question is why `<component>` is not nesting inside `<router-outlet>`, and becomes a sibling.

However, this CSS is not applied on `<component>` tag:

```
app sidebar main-content > * {
   background: red;
}
```

When we check, `<router-outlet>` has this style, but `<component>` which is the direct child of `<main-content>` doesn't have this style.

What is wrong here?

Comment: All descendants are direct, the `>` symbol is the **child combinator** (formerly known as the *child selector* before selectors and combinators were separated)

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Elements panel. Look at the `<component>` element. Look at the Styles tab. Is the style applied according to that? Is it overridden by something? Is it applied but not visible (e.g. because there is no height for it to be visible in)? Is the `<component>` really the child of the `<main-content>`?

Comment: for the style you have to use :host /deep/ to apply the style to the nested component

Comment: No style is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stated code:

```
<app>
   <sidebar></sidebar>
   <main-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <component></component>
   </main-content>
</app>
```

this

```
app sidebar main-content > * {
   background: red;
}
```

will not work because `main-content` is not a child of `sidebar` but is a **sibling**.

**I'd suggest you try**

```
app sidebar + main-content > * {
   background: red;
}
```

or even

```
app main-content > * {
   background: red;
}
```